# Sql vs nosql for a realtime messaging app?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine, nosql

I am creating a messaging app. I have my users stored in a mysql database and messages stored in google datastore a nosql database. However I was wondering what would be the drawbacks of having my messages in a mysql database since I am fetching the message and the user simultaneously.

Is there performance drawbacks?

Comment: For what purpose do you wanna use it?  Pleae explain your situation a bit more so we can give you an better advice.

Comment: So it is easily scalable with faster performance @Noob

Answer (score 2):

Generally, different database usage cannot affect anything if your backend architecture is well-defined. Database stores only data to manipulate. I think for authentication you use mySQL and store data in Google Datastore. Performance drawbacks are coming from the bandwidth of your server.

I propose that you must use the same database to store all data, it will be more stable and easy to manage.

Comment: So for a messaging app do you recommend to migrate my data to mySql or nosql @RTE